# Image data not being sent to Imgur API for base64 image javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, base64, imgur

I'm trying to upload an image to an imgur album using the imgur api for a personal project, but when I run test the code, I get the following message:

"data": {
"error": "No image data was sent to the upload api",
"request": "/3/image",
"method": "POST"
},
"success": false,
"status": 400
}

I have the following code (which I found online and have slightly modified):

```
var img = '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';
$.ajax({
                        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
                        type: 'post',
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Client-ID aaaaaaa' //omitted
                        },
                        data: {
                            image: img, //This is the base64 link, which works when pasted into chrome and I have removed 'data:image/png;base64,'
                            type: 'base64',
                            album: 'aaaaaa' //omitted
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(json) {
                            console.log(json);
                        },
                        error: function(json) {
                            console.log(json);
                        }
                    });
```

To test the code, I am running it in the postman test script feature, which is where I get the error (I also replace ajax with pm.sendRequest()). Also, all of my keys, ID's, and the image itself are not the problem.

Any ideas? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: docs need changing, one says `/3/image` other says `/3/upload`, try the later

Comment: When I try upload, I get a "Bad Request" error